# how to prove the fundamental group isomorphic?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Suppose $f:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is continuous and has no fixed point.

> How can we prove that $f_*:\pi_1(X,x_0)\rightarrow\pi_1(X,f(x_0))$ is a group isomorphism where $f_*([\sigma]) = [f \circ \sigma]$ for all $[\sigma] \in \pi_1(X,x_0)$?

Comment: If $f$ has no fixed point, then $x_0\neq f(x_0)$. So shouldn't your isomorphism be $f_*:\pi_1(S^1,x_0) \to \pi_1(S^1,f(x_0))?$ Also, I'm assuming that your space $X$ is $S^1$.

Comment: sorry for my  mistake

Comment: An **isomorphism** between two groups is a bijective function that preserves the group structure. On the other hand, two groups are **isomorphic** if there exists an isomorphism between them.

Comment: Thanks,I am courious about how to make use of the property that $f$ has no fiexed point to prove this problem

Answer (score 2):

I presume that $X$ is $S^1$.

Model $S^1$ by $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ and take $x_0$ to be the image of $0$.
The map $f:\Bbb R/\Bbb Z\to\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ induces $F:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$. As $\Bbb R$ is simply connected, and also is the universal cover
of $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$, then $F$ lifts to $\tilde F:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$.
As $f$ has no fixed points, then $G(x)=\tilde F(x)-x$ is never an integer.
But $\tilde F(1)-\tilde F(0)$ is an integer and so $G(1)-G(0)$
is an integer. By continuity $G(x)$ always lies in some interval
$(m,m+1)$ ($m\in \Bbb Z$) and so $G(1)=G(0)$ that is $\tilde F(1)=\tilde F(0)+1$. Now $f$ is homotopic to the identity map by a homotopy
$H:(x,t)\mapsto (1-t)\tilde F(x)-tx$. The crucial thing here is that
$H(x+1,t)=H(x,t)$. As $f$ is homotopic to the identity map, it induces
an isomorphism on the fundamental groups.